# Need SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, gexperts

```
incident_number   Has_Breached   Id
INC15229006       Breached       1
INC15229006       Not Breached   2
INC15229006       Not Breached   3
INC15087939       Not Breached   4
INC15087939       Not Breached   5
INC15087939       Not Breached   6
INC15087939       Not Breached   7
INC15087939       Breached       8
INC15087939       Not Breached   9
INC15087939       Breached       10
INC15087940       Not Breached   13
INC15087940       Not Breached   12
INC15087940       Not Breached   24
INC15087940       Not Breached   32
INC15087940       Not Breached   45
INC15087940       Not Breached   67
```

I need results like below

```
incident_number   Has_Breached
INC15229006       Breached
INC15087939       Breached
INC15087940       Not Breached
```

Comment: Would you care to explain the logic behind this?

Comment: if any one of the rows marked as breached, the final results should be breached for that INC

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. If you want code written for you, hire someone to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the possible values are only `'Breachend'` and `'Not Breached'`, you can `GROUP BY incident_number` and get the minimum as `'Breached' < 'Not Breached'`.

```
SELECT incident_number,
       min(has_breached) has_breached
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY incident_number;
```

Comment: Superb, this is working. I also need how many breaches per Incident in next column, will that be possible?